# using nhibernate t-sql table-valued user-defined functions

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, hql, user-defined-functions

Is it possible to use *table t-sql table-valued user-defined* function as part of HQL query ?

here [Nhibernate filtering by user defined function output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706259/nhibernate-filtering-by-user-defined-function-output) is a example how to create custom dialect extention but in this example scalar UDF is used.

Let's assume that I have following t-sql UDT

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getSuitableProjects]  
(
    @userID INT  
)  
RETURNS @result TABLE   
(  
    ProjectID INT  
)  
AS  
-- body of the function ..
```

I would like to be able to write following hql - second line is pseudocode, simply I would like to invoke my function as part of hql query - real query is more complicated it has fetch joins etc.

```
StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();  
hql.AppendLine("select p from Projects p WHERE p.ProjectID IN");  
hql.AppendLine("(run with parameter -> getSuitableProjects(:userID))");

IQuery q = UOW.Session.CreateQuery(hql.ToString());  
q.SetInt32("userID", userID);
```

I spend some time looking for answer but without results. Is it possible ?
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: I had a doubt similiar to yours, have a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812235/select-from-table-valued-function-nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a table-valued function with HQL.

Use SQL (`CreateSQLQuery(...)`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will find it usefull, I've ended with following query

```
var query = UOW.Session.QueryOver<Project>();
query = query.Where(...) //where  citeria which can be expressed in QueryOver
query = query.Fetch(z => z.Items).Eager.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

var criteria = query.UnderlyingCriteria
.Add(Expression.Sql("{alias}.ID IN (SELECT ProjectID FROM dbo.getSuitableProjects(12))"))
```

My goal was to have items preloaded (*z.Items*) and simultaniously to restrict to only those projects which are available for user -> this logic sits in my table value UDF.